# Problem with Loading initial ramdisk in Archlinux (character firing)

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader, escape-characters, ramdisk

In the boot arch initial (Loading initial ramdisk) some characters are appearing, photo below:

[image: boot arch initial]

As well as when switching off, the same characters also appear, photo below:

[image: Close the section]

However, sometimes (actually about 2 times) I enter and exit the OS without these characters appearing. I installed my OS on  October 2, 2023.

Could anyone tell me what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: After scourin' the web, I found out the snag was with the laptop keyboard. The delete key was short-circuitin', causin' this string of characters to pop up (which matched the ones on the delete key). Tried usin' an external keyboard, but even then, those characters kept showin' up. The hitch was only fixed by swapping out the laptop keyboard.